# SoundCloud API - retrieve tracks uploaded from my app

Tags: soundcloud

As an iOS application owner, I would like to know whether the SoundCloud API allows me to grab a list of tracks (and their URLs) uploaded from my application.

The documentation is not very clear in this respect, as it does not provide a clear list of parameters to send, more specifically it implies using an ID parameter which is simply described as "an Integer ID".

Can anyone who has achieved this result give me some guidance in this respect?

PS - posting here as SoundCloud support page indicates that their team will answer technical questions here.

Answer (score 0):

agreed, the literature on this is very vague

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#apps

Soundcloud support claims that "Our team is answering technical questions on Stack Overflow"

i hope they can provide an answer to this